# Display image on the JLabel area when selecting item in the JCombobBox

Tags: java, swing

I can't add images to `JLabel` to display the image on the `JLabel` area  when I select the item in the `JCombobBox`.

There should be the images of mug, lighter and the keyring in `JLabel`, so just wrote photo in the code. However I could not deal with it.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.*;   

public class comb extends JFrame  {
  JLabel lb3;

  public comb(){

    JLabel lb1 =  new JLabel("photo");

    lb1.setBounds(270,80,100,100);

    String[] product = new String[]{"Mug","lighter","keyring"};

    JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(product);
    cb.setBounds(20, 50, 100, 20);

    add(lb1);
    add(cb);

    setTitle("Window");
    setSize(500,500);
    this.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    new comb();
  }
}
```

Comment: "*However I could not deal with it.*" > That's a really poor description of your problem. What exactly is going wrong with your code?

Comment: Please clarify what the problem is, based on your post it's not very clear.  Also please fix the formatting in your code.

Comment: If it's not to much to deal with, please remember to accept answers that may have helped you solve your issues.

Comment: Thanks for your guys advices. you are so helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to display the image on the JLabel area when i select the item in the JCombobBox.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Combo Boxes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html). There is a working example that does exactly this.

The tutorial will:

1. Show you how to write the `ActionListener` required to respond to the selection of the item in the combo box
2. Better strucuture you program to that your GUI is created on the `Event Dispatch Thread`.
3. Create a GUI by NOT extending JFrame.

So, get rid of you code and start over with the example in the tutorial for a better designed program.

The Swing tutorial is the place to start for basic Swing questions.

Comment: one more quesion,  why the GUI should not extend JFrame?

Comment: @Laddie, don't forget to "accept" the answer that helped solve your problem. `why the GUI should not extend JFrame?` you should only extend a class when you add new functionality to the class. Search the web using "composition vs inheritance" for more information on the subject.

Comment: @Laddie, and yet you still haven't "accepted" an answer!

Comment: @Laddie, `I will accept answers firend` - and yet you still haven't "accepted" any answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try This: 
Based on selecting combobox item create ImageIcon with respective image url and set to JLable.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(picUrl); 
JLabel label = new JLabel();
label.setIcon(icon);
```

Note: picUrl is string of file path.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Thanks for your guys advices. you are so helpful

Answer (score 0):

you can create image icon like this

---

```
    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setLabelFor(label);
    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(".\\image/location or name.jpg"));
    label.setBounds(10, 22, 30, 30);
    contentPane.add(label);
```

Comment: Don' use setBounds(). It is the job of the layout manager to determine the size/location of a component.

Comment: Thanks for your guys advices. you are so helpful